# Change Google locality settings

Tags: google-search, localization

I was recently using a VPN on Google Chrome and was on Google a lot. Now the search engine and other websites have switched to the country settings of the country the VPN was accessing.

Is there a way I can change back to my local settings?

Answer (score 0):

I guess one option would be to use the website without the VPN for a while, otherwise you should be able to change the settings on each website.